# Creating a new user in Planetscale results in weird error

Tags: planetscale

This might seem extremely simple for some, and usually works easilly for me, but I can't understand why it keeps failing. I've created a MySQL database on Planetscale, and I want to create a new user using mysql, I run this command that seems perfectly correct:

```
CREATE USER 'migration_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'complexpassword123';
```

But I constantly get this error:

> Error Code: 1105. syntax error at position 12 near 'USER'

What is wrong with this command ? Normally it should just work.

Comment: What are you trying to do with  '%'

Comment: the host, when I replace '%' with a valid ip address, it still fails.

Comment: This is not a mysql error message. Planetscale us mysql compatible, but is not mysql. You should check its manual for creating users.

Answer (score 2):

Planetscale is “MySQL compatible” but is *not* actually MySQL under the hood. It does not support using `CREATE USER` from the MySQL command line interface:

> `CREATE USER` won't work on the MySQL command-line with a PlanetScale database.

[<sup>Source</sup>](https://github.com/planetscale/discussion/discussions/221#discussioncomment-2996076)

Use the Planetscale administration panel’s Password feature to generate a new user account with access to your database.